# State is not retaining in checkbox

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, web, checkbox

There is a check box in my webform. whenever i tick it ..and click on back button it will not retain its state ..when i comeback using the next button to the same page.

Note: view state is enabled in the control

There is no code in the page load event

Code below:

```
Protected Sub chkBx_SR_wu_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles chkBx_SR_wu.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Try
        For i = 0 To chkBx_SR_wu.Items.Count - 1
            If chkBx_SR_wu.Items(i).Selected Then
                Select Case chkBx_SR_wu.Items(i).Value
                    Case "SR_MR"
                        chkbx_SR.Checked = True
                    Case "Sk_MR"
                        chkbx_SkRoom.Checked = True
                    Case "SC_SS"
                        chkbx_admin.Checked = True
                    Case "CS_MR"
                        chkbx_salesFloor.Checked = True
                    Case "TEAM_LEADER"
                        rb_tl.Enabled = True
                        chkbx_tlAdmin.Enabled = True
                        chkbx_tlJewellery.Enabled = True
                        chkbx_tlSalesFloor.Enabled = True
                        chkbx_tlSkRoom.Enabled = True
                        rb_tl.Items(0).Enabled = True
                        rb_tl.Items(1).Enabled = True
                        rb_tl.Items(2).Enabled = True
                        rb_tl.Items(3).Enabled = True
                        ReqiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = True



                End Select
            Else
                Select Case chkBx_SR_wu.Items(i).Value
                    Case "SR_MR"
                        chkbx_SR.Enabled = False
                        chkbx_SR.Checked = False
                    Case "Sk_MR"
                        chkbx_SkRoom.Enabled = False
                        chkbx_SkRoom.Checked = False
                    Case "SC_SS"
                        chkbx_admin.Enabled = False
                        chkbx_admin.Checked = False
                    Case "CS_MR"
                        chkbx_salesFloor.Enabled = False
                        chkbx_salesFloor.Checked = False
                    Case "TEAM_LEADER"
                        chkbx_tlAdmin.Enabled = False
                        chkbx_tlAdmin.Checked = False
                        chkbx_tlJewellery.Enabled = False
                        chkbx_tlJewellery.Checked = False
                        chkbx_tlSalesFloor.Enabled = False
                        chkbx_tlSalesFloor.Checked = False
                        chkbx_tlSkRoom.Enabled = False
                        chkbx_tlSkRoom.Checked = False
                        rb_tl.Items(0).Enabled = False
                        rb_tl.Items(1).Enabled = False
                        rb_tl.Items(2).Enabled = False
                        rb_tl.Items(3).Enabled = False
                        ReqiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = False
                End Select
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub"
```

Comment: If you're not posting the form to server, it's not a viewstate case.

Comment: Then how it can be done.

Comment: Moreover, when i click on Next button to the new page and comeback state is retained.

But when i click on the back button and come to the same page state is not retained

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes don't use ViewState to retain their state - they use the contents of the HTTP POST payload to determine whether or not to set the control as `Checked`.

If you need to persist this value beyond the normal postback cycle you will need to store it in session or somewhere similar that will survive beyond that timeframe.

Comment: Could you explain a bit .. how to store it in session?

Comment: If you can, please post some of your code so that I can help you create a solution that will work for you.

Comment: Code has been give above..please look

Comment: Moreover, when i click on Next button to the new page and comeback state is retained.

But when i click on the back button and come to the same page state is not retained